# IE7/IE8 page-break-after:always not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, page-break

In Firefox the `page-break-after: always;` directive is working fine. However, this same code is seemingly ignored by IE. To test, copy and paste the code into a new HTML document before saving and then testing the print preview. During print preview, I want the page-break-after directive to actually do what it says, like it does in Firefox.

The entire code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    margin: 0;
    font-style: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    clear: both;
}
div.header
{
    display: block;
}
div.header img
{
    height: 160px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.left
{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 550px
}
div.right
{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    min-height: 550px;
    page-break-after: always;
}
div.last
{
    min-height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    page-break-after: always;
}
div.images
{
}
div.images img
{
    max-height: 240px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img.smaller
{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h3
{
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}
h3.blurb
{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
hr.line
{

}
span.blurb
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
span.memories
{

}
span.activities
{

}
span.university
{

}
span.children
{

}
span.hobbies
{

}
span.volunteer
{

}
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
div.left
{
    height: expression( document.body.clientHeight > 550 ? "550px" : "auto" );
}
div.right
{
    height: expression( document.body.clientHeight > 550 ? "550px" : "auto" );
}
div.images img
{
    height: expression( document.body.clientHeight > 240 ? "240px" : "auto" );
}
img.smaller
{
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;   
}

img
{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /></div>
<div class="left">
    <h3>Name:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />


    <h3>Current Name:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Address:</h3> 2345 Vivamus et Tellus Street
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Home Phone:</h3> 9096761212
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Cell Phone:</h3> 9096761212
    <hr class="line" />


    <h3>Email:</h3> lipsum@marius.com
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Employer/Retired:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Job Title:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Are you planning to attend reunion?</h3> Yes
    <hr class="line" />


    <h3 class="blurb">Memories:</h3>
    <span class="blurb memories">None provided</span>

    <h3 class="blurb">Student Activities/Clubs:</h3>
    <span class="blurb activities">None provided</span>
</div>
<div class="right" style="page-break-after: always;">
    <h3>Major:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame
    <hr class="line" />


    <h3>Spouse/partner name:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Spouse/partner employer:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Spouse/partner job title:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3 class="blurb">Spouse/Partner University and Class Year:</h3>

    <span class="blurb university">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli</span>

    <h3 class="blurb">Children (list names/ages):</h3>
    <span class="blurb children">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, Sed quis nunc, Aliquam</span>

    <h3 class="blurb">Interests/Hobbies:</h3>
    <span class="blurb hobbies">Lorem ipsum dolor</span>

    <h3 class="blurb">Volunteer Work (include services):</h3>

    <span class="blurb volunteer">None provided</span>
</div>
<div class="last" style="page-break-after: always;">
    <h3 class="blurb">Life since</h3>
    <span class="blurb life">None provided</span>
</div>


<div class="header"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /></div>
<div class="left">
    <h3>Name:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />


    <h3>Current Name:</h3> Lorem ipsum
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Address:</h3> None provided
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Home Phone:</h3> None provided
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Cell Phone:</h3> None provided
    <hr class="line" />


    <h3>Email:</h3> None provided
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Employer/Retired:</h3> None provided
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Job Title:</h3> None provided
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Are you planning to attend reunion?</h3> Yes
    <hr class="line" />


    <h3 class="blurb">Memories:</h3>
    <span class="blurb memories">None provided</span>

    <h3 class="blurb">Student Activities/Clubs:</h3>
    <span class="blurb activities">None provided</span>
</div>
<div class="right" style="page-break-after: always;">
    <h3>Major:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame
    <hr class="line" />


    <h3>Spouse/partner name:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Spouse/partner employer:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3>Spouse/partner job title:</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli
    <hr class="line" />

    <h3 class="blurb">Spouse/Partner University and Class Year:</h3>

    <span class="blurb university">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli</span>

    <h3 class="blurb">Children (list names/ages):</h3>
    <span class="blurb children">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, Sed quis nunc, Aliquam</span>

    <h3 class="blurb">Interests/Hobbies:</h3>
    <span class="blurb hobbies">Lorem ipsum dolor</span>

    <h3 class="blurb">Volunteer Work (include services):</h3>

    <span class="blurb volunteer">None provided</span>
</div>
<div class="last" style="page-break-after: always;">
    <h3 class="blurb">Life since</h3>
    <span class="blurb life">None provided</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for answering a question with a question, but could it be because the page-breaks are being applied on positioned elements?

MSDN clearly states that

> Page breaks are not permitted inside positioned objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530842(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: as you can see from my code, I am not using the position directive. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I was thinking, and could be horribly wrong, that the `Float` tag could potentially be counted as a positioning tag.

Comment: Well, thanks. Because the article doesn't specify and position is a reserved word in CSS, I am nearly certain that they are referring to the position directive specifically.

Comment: Looks like you were right bPratik. See my last comment if interested.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 1):

page-break( after and before )is not enough for internet explorer **by own**. If u try this, you can see the result. I have same problem but I solved by this way.

```html
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
<div>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of inline elements. I was unable to get `page-break-after: always;` to work on `<br>` and `<span>` in IE, but it worked fine on a `<div>`.

```
<br style="page-break-after: always;">          <!-- does not work -->
<span style="page-break-after: always;"></span> <!-- does not work -->
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>   <!-- this works! -->
```